# Add an Equal Widths constraint using the Xamarin iOS Designer

Tags: ios, xamarin, constraints, xamarin-studio

In my Xamarin app, I am trying to add a single view to a scroll view. Based on recommendations online, I am trying to set an Equal Widths Constraint between the view and the main view of the controller, but I don't see any way to do it in the Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio designers.

Can this type of constraint be added using the designer?

Comment: Can you try by selecting both view and main view simultaneously the add equal with through pin.

Comment: Hi @jkh, did you find a proper way to solve this? I've read that opening it in xcode could do the trick, but I'm interested in solving this within Xamarin Designer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set equal widths between views by doing the following (screenshots to follow):

1. In the Xamarin iOS Designer, put the designer in `Constraint Editing Mode`
2. Click the view you want to make equal width to another (in my screenshot, the `Label`).
3. This reveals the view constraints. Hold `CTRL`, then click and drag on the sideways `I` in the middle-bottom of the view. You'll notice a blue line appears. Hover your mouse over the destination view you want to make equal widths to and let go.

[image]

[image]